# Neutrino Oscillation ($\nu_{\mu} \to \nu_{\tau}$)

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

Why is tau-appearance channel called silver channel?

Answer (score 0):

There are three channels, gold, silver, platinum.

The threshold and energy resolution of the golden channel has the most promising optimization (lower the muon energy).

The platinum channel includes the electron neutrino charge identification, with large values of mixing angle.

The silver channel is for charge identification for tau neutrinos of intermediate mixing angle values.

> For example, the
>   correlation with the phase δCP can be completely resolved if the golden channel measurement
>   is performed at the so-called “magic baseline” at approximately 7500 km. At this baseline,
>   by definition the condition sin(Aˆ∆) = 0 is fulfilled and only the term T1 remains, while
>   T2, T3, and T4 vanish (cf., Eq. (3) to Eq. (5)). Therefore, a clean measurement of sin2
>   2θ13
>   becomes possible [55]. Note that one looses the sensitivity to the CP phase at the magic
>   baseline, and thus needs an additional detector at a different baseline for a measurements
>   of δCP.
>   The two additional appearance channels, the silver νe → ντ channel [56] and the platinum
>   νµ → νe channel [57] in principle allow to reduce the effects of correlations and degeneracies
>   since there the dependence on the oscillation parameters is slightly different.

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0606119

Comment: Minor comment: please link to arXiv abstracts, not to PDFs.

Comment: Thank you, but could you tell me specifically if there is any reason it's called "silver channel"

Comment: @SheebaShafaq gold, silver, platinum is just a level of order for naming them in where the gold is the main channel.